Auto-redirect on session timeout in React + Spring & Tomcat
I have a web app with Spring backend and React frontend.
Session timeout is set to 30 minutes, the default time coming from Apache Tomcat. Right now, when the session expires and user refreshes the page once it’s expired he’s redirected to login page - great.
But my goal is to automatically redirect him without the need to manually refresh the page, because right now he can continue to e.g open modals, switch tabs within my web app, just not fetch the data since endpoints respond with errors once the session timed out. But until he manually refreshes, he’s not taken to the login page.
What I tried:
One idea was to make a controller with a method just for checking if session is active, make requests to that endpoint e.g. every minute and based on the response redirect to login. But that’s not possible because any time I make a request, it resets the session and starts the expiration time again from 0 so as a result the session never expires (I read it’s how Tomcat handles it and I didn’t find any possible solution)
Any ideas on how I could achieve the desired effect, or at least something close to it?
